# Use of secondary findings to motivate novelty

Tags: publishability

I have a paper on machine learning with a clear research objective and goals. Further, our experiments show that our proposed methodology actually meets those goals and perform better than the state-of-the-art methods in the field.

After two rounds of review, so in the third feedback, one reviewer for the fist time mentioned that the paper lacks novelty. Without pointing to the overlapping literature. We are sure this is not the case since our section Related Work covers most, if not all, of the methods in our research field.

In order to improve the novelty in our work, I have been playing around with our proposed model, and found some interesting results. These results are of course the consequence of our proposed methodology.

So my question is can I use those findings to motivate novelty in our research? As I mentioned before, our experiments show that our proposed models solves the research objectives. So I dont want to miss that focus. I just would like to point to future research based on the new fidings, and ideally use those findings to improve the novelty of the manuscript. So the one reviewer that mentioned the novelty part suggests to accept the paper. The other two reviewers have already suggested acceptance.

Comment: Do you mean "novelty"?

Comment: "So I dont want to miss that focus. I just would like to point to future research based on the new fidings, and ideally use those findings to improve the novelity of the manuscript" When you don't present the findings as part of your paper, you cannot use them to argue for novelty. A better strategy would be to kindly ask the reviewer to clarify his doubts about the paper's novelty -- which previous works with the same findings exist?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper we have already asked, via the EiC, about a clarification, but we did not get a concrete answer. Just a "please review the manuscript accordingly". I am planning to include the findings in the paper, but I am not sure how to present them without missing the focus of our research. Further, I am not sure how can I argue that the findings are some sort of novelty.

Comment: "We explain the novelty of our work in the introduction and in Sect. <Related_Work>. To the best of our knowledge, our discussion of related work does not contain any omissions. If we are wrong, we kindly ask reviewer X to specify the omitted works."

Comment: If you plan to include the new findings, why do you mention future work in your question?

Comment: user1571823, how *complicated* is the new methodology that you introduce in the paper? I've seen a couple of times that if something surprisingly simple solves an important problem, then some reviewers feel that this is not worthy of publication because....well hard to say why exactly. Perhaps because they feel that the technical contribution just isn't enough for a good venue? This is a just q a question to figure out what the reviewer may really want.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper because I feel that the fidings point in a different direction than the main focus of the paper. Hence I beleive that if it is some value on it, it should be investigated in a research with a different angle. But my point is if we can argue that our proposed methodology, in addition to perform better than the state-of-the-art, has opened a new avenue for future research based of the new findings.

Comment: @DCTLib well, we beleive that we have made contributions to core machine learning literature, and we dont find any other similar work out there. We will submit a revised manuscript, but given that the reviewer rising the issue about novelty did not provide a concrete example, we are highligting the contributions of our paper. Additionally, I would like to add the new findings to support the novelty of our methoddoly, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: @user1571823 Note that I was not asking whether you made good contributions, but rather whether they look complicated or like a "deep insight". I know that this doesn't matter, but I just have the *guess* that the reviewer may be uneasy suggesting acceptance of something that works well with simple methods. That being the case would at least be consistent with the reviewer being unable to give a concrete example - he/she wants *one* so-called "deep insight" and may be unable to find any insight in your paper that classifies as "deep", measures by how complicated they are.

Comment: @DCTLib I see your point. Difficult to answer, but we have introduced concepts that make our proposed model more complex than other methods in the field. Actually we present two models, one more complex than the other. Whether the reviewer see our model simple or complex is relative I would say. But I see your point, and that might explain why we did not get a concrete feedback.